# Is "mystery" an abstract noun?

Tags: nouns, abstract-nouns

I think "mystery" is an abstract noun but I want to see your explanations.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by abstract?

Comment: It might be useful if you state why you think mystery is an abstract noun  with some support for your argument and then we can  respectfully agree or disagree with support for our opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.  While you can say something abstract like:

> The old house was surrounded with an aura of **mystery**.

You can also say:

> It was a **mystery** what happened to the owners of the old house.

Is this abstract?  It seems to depend on personal opinion.  "A mystery" defines a concrete set of circumstances, no less than something like "a meeting" or "a vacation".  But you can't hold it in your hand.

I think you need to define what exactly you mean by "abstract", otherwise this question really has no definitive answer.

Comment: This answer might be misleading that *count* nouns are always *concrete*.  "A story" is always abstract.  "A book" is always concrete.

Comment: @amI  I think it depends on your definition of "abstract" and "concrete".  You might say a *story* is "abstract" because you can't hold it in your hands, while I might say it is "concrete" because it represents something with defined boundaries (as compared with something like *mystery* that is completely conceptual).  I'm not saying you're wrong, but rather that you have to clarify the semantics before we can agree.

Comment: Be careful -- if you talk about 'a mystery' then it can have defined boundaries just like 'a story'.  I see the fuzzy area more in dimensions, like 'time','space','energy', (which I prefer abstract) and in units, like 'hours','feet','pounds' (which I prefer concrete).

Comment: @ami  Well, that's what I mean in my answer when I say it could be either.  **A mystery** has defined boundaries (e.g. it exists until some meddling kids and their dog solve it), while the general concept of **mystery** (as in "Mystery, Inc") does not.

Comment: That just makes the distinction useless.  Count/mass can be cued by syntactic context, but concrete/abstract relies on semantic definition.  Just because you can count examples of a concept doesn't make each of those countable examples concrete.  The meaningful use of 'concrete' depends on the ability to make real comparisons with real physical objects (while abstract things manifest themselves only in the *pattern* of different physical objects).